# How to customize and display the round icon on click of bottom tab

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I am working on bottom tabs in xamarin forms. I am looking for a sample application in xamarin forms for bottom tabs same as the in the video provided for android.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz_il-BMaD0

Could anybody please help me with this task?

Comment: [Custom tabs](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/501) in XCT would help?

Comment: Hi can you tell me if any example available in xamarin forms for curved bottom navigation tabs similar to this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJ_-euBIhyU

Comment: @user1448108 You can take a look [this sample](https://github.com/ahoefling/XamarinShellSamples/tree/master/Samples/Samples.ShellItemRenderer) firstly.

Comment: Hi Cherry, I tried this url and able to run the app...in that example the center tab is not navigating to corresponding screen when i clicked on it..tried debugging but did not understood where its failing...can you check once

Answer (score 1):

This nuget is helpful in customizing UI for tabs.

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs